# What determines when a yum group is installed?

Tags: rpm, yum, rpm-spec

I have created a yum repo, and along with it I have created a group to install some of these RPMs.  However, if I have not yet installed this group with groupinstall, but some of the other rpms have been installed by something else, then performing a 'yum grouplist' will show that my group is installed even though the majority of the rpms have not yet been installed.

If I then do a 'yum gruopinstall MYGROUP' then it installs the rest of the rpms in that group.  But why does my group show up as installed before all of the rpms are installed?  What determines when a group is "installed"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding the yum code correctly (and looking in the right place) it would appear that if all of the `mandatory` group packages are installed then the group is considered installed.

From the code [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/gitweb?p=yum.git;a=blob;f=yum/comps.py;h=92e87bab51e45a4f32938ef4dc09038fb35201ec;hb=HEAD#l848)